FlashForge Adventurer 4 Bed levelling back to front issues
We have an Adventurer 4 printer at my job, that has mostly been used for fun projects outside of work, but not so much any longer. I started at this job just a few months ago and I have used the printer for some small parts since then, but now want to print a few larger stuff, and make sure that we can reliably use the printer for customer prototyping as well.
I got a lot of problems with adheison at first. I tried to do some calibration and did get some improvements, but still poor. The build plate was quite scratched and old, so I bought some new flexible PEI plates that I think have a much better texture. This helped with adheison, and small parts placed in the middle of the plate works great now. Larger stuff is still very poor quality.
I did various tests with the calibration and printed multiple single layer tests in all corners. Here is what is looks like:

The middle part is in my opinion good. The front seems to have the nozzle too low/close to the plate. The back seems to have the nozzle too high/far away from the plate. I also see this if I do the 9-point levelling, where the front points are +0.5 and back points are -0.5 compared to the middle.
Left to right seems to be OK levelled I think.
I know now that the 9-point levelling just collects inte a single average, which is very unfortunate.
Does anyone know of any ways to improve the bed levelness in my case? Is it the heating base that is not level? Or could there be some issue when the bed moves back and forth?
One idea I thought I might try is to simply put a piece of tape below the back of the plate, to raise that up. Could that work? Or do you have any other ideas?

The Aventurer 4 was released in 2021 and you just recently started using this machine; therefore others have used this machine before you. Have you checked to see if the bed itself (not the PEI sheet) is warped?

@agarza Yes, others have used it before me, and seen similar issues but never cared enough to fix them.
No, I haven't checked the bed itself for warpness, I will check that! If it is, would buying a new bed/heater solve my issues?

After investigating more closely, I was able to level the bed. I removed the whole heater base and checked for any problems below. After wiping off some minor debris I reattached the heater base once more, and probably tightned the screws more than before. After then recalibrating the bed is almost completely level.
So it turns out to have been an easy fix for me, maybe this will help someone else.
